# error importing pandas/matplotlib in cgi-bin script

Tags: python, apache, matplotlib, pandas, cgi

I'm attempting to import pandas in a simple Python script that I'm running on an Apache web server. For some reason pandas is not importing. When I look at the Apache error log it appears the error actually comes from importing matplotlib:

```
Premature end of script headers: hello_advanced.cgi
Traceback (most recent call last):\r
  File "C:/OSGeo4W/apache/cgi-bin/hello_advanced.cgi", line 14, in <module>\r
    import pandas\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>\r
    from pandas.core.api import *\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\api.py", line 12, in <module>\r
    from pandas.core.series import Series, TimeSeries\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\series.py", line 2617, in <module>\r
    import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\tools\\plotting.py", line 23, in <module>\r
    import pandas.tseries.converter as conv\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\tseries\\converter.py", line 7, in <module>\r
    import matplotlib.units as units\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py", line 947, in <module>\r
    rcParams = rc_params()\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py", line 856, in rc_params\r
    fname = matplotlib_fname()\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py", line 726, in matplotlib_fname\r
    configdir = _get_configdir()\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py", line 597, in _get_configdir\r
    return _get_config_or_cache_dir(_get_xdg_config_dir())\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py", line 534, in _get_xdg_config_dir\r
    return os.environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME', os.path.join(get_home(), '.config'))\r
  File "C:\\Python27\\Anaconda\\lib\\ntpath.py", line 96, in join\r
    assert len(path) > 0\r
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()\r
```

I would appreciate any input on why this is happening and how to resolve it. I can rework the script to avoid pandas but I don't want to have to do that each time I reach an import error.

Comment: How did you install `pandas`?

Comment: It's seems to expect a config file in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. Could you try `import os; os.environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME')` from the interpreter?

Comment: @Ffisegydd - it came with my Anaconda install

Comment: @TomAugspurger - you're getting warmer, when I do that it returns None - would this be something that I set in my CGI configuration?

Comment: The problem is that that the `hello_advanced.cgi` script is expecting a config file to be there, but it can't find it. [This](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/matplot-crases-because-of-XDG-CONFIG-HOME-variable-td43370.html) may be related.